# Google Sheets copyTo referencing a Dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two Sheets: Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Sheet1!A1 has a dropdown.
Sheet2!A1 references the value in A1: `=Sheet1!A1`

I want to use scripting to copy all values/formats to a third Sheet, Sheet3.

**Solution 1:**
Normally this would be a simple `copyTo`.

```
Sheet2.copyTo(Sheet3);

Exception: The data you entered in cell A1 violates the data validation rules set on this cell.
```

However, an error pops up around Data Validation.
Apparently Sheet2!A1 inherits the Dropdown Data Validation from Sheet1, so copyTo fails?

**Solution 2**
Copy the values first and then the formatting.
Though there is a quick way to getValues and setValues, I can't find a way to copy all the formatting over.
Going individually thru all the format options (`getFontColor`/`setFontColor`, `getBackground`/`setBackground`, etc.) would be too ridiculous as I want to copy over all formatting.

Anyone have any solutions or workarounds?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. About `Sheet2.copyTo(Sheet3);`, do you want to copy all values including the cell format from "Sheet2" to "Sheet3"? And, can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating your current issue of `Exception: The data you entered in cell A1 violates the data validation rules set on this cell.`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: `var Sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
var Sheet3 = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
Sheet2.copyTo(Sheet3);`

This is the entire script.  I want to copy all values + ALL formatting.
This does not work if Sheet2 references Sheet1 and Sheet1 has a Dropdown (Sheet1!A1 has dropdown, Sheet2!A1 `=Sheet2!A2`